# Submit HTML form data to a div element without refreshing a page

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have slide down panel created in JQuery into a table, that panel contains contact form. I need to post that form data, but prevent to reload all page after submit button is hitted, because after page reload, slide down panel also reloads and it shrinks. I need only refresh the div element to get form data to PHP.

```
<div id="form">
    <form id="form" action="/">
       <br />
                <p>
                <label for="name"><small>Name *</small></label><br />
                  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" size="15" />

                </p>
                <p>
                   <label for="email"><small>Mail *</small></label><br />
                  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" size="15" />

                </p>
                <p>
                <label for="comments"><small>Message *</small></label>
                  <textarea name="comments" id="comments" rows="10" cols="5"></textarea>
                </p>
                <p>
                  <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Send" />
                  &nbsp;
                  <input name="reset" type="reset" id="reset" tabindex="5" value="Reset" />
                </p>
              </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first make submit button:

```
<input name="submit" type="button" id="submit" value="Send" />
```

Then use this:

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
  $.post("test.php", $("#form").serialize());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g3Ubh/